# CloudFlare giving error 522 without HTTPS

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, cloudflare, lets-encrypt

I've set up Let's Encrypt (with nginx) on my server, following the tutorial I've linked in the comments. I've also set up CloudFlare with the following DNS settings:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV8lf.png

And my nginx configuration looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ^~ /.well-known/ {
        allow all;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

If I go to `https://www.example.com`, the site loads fine. But when I go to `http://www.example.com` (not HTTPS), it shows an Error 522:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTJ5A.png

What's wrong? How do I fix this? Why isn't my redirect working?

Comment: The Let's Encrypt tutorial I followed: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read [CloudFlare's 522 connection timeout guide](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171906-Error-522-Connection-timed-out)? Do you have SSL set to "full SSL"? For me that's within page rules, but there may be a global setting.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It was actually my server's firewall blocking their IPs.

Comment: Yeah that'll do it.

Answer (score 1):

check your Inbound firewall rules for ec2 - make sure port 80 / 443 are exposed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've already contacted CloudFlare's support team, right?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

you don't have the server_name set to serve  www.example.com  but in your HTTPS example you have both example.com and www.example.com

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
...
```

Comment: Yes, I've contacted CloudFlare and am awaiting a response. I've included `www.example.com` in the `server_name`, but that hasn't solved the issue.